# count duplicates, then drop them

Tags: python, pandas

When I print out this:         `print(ids)`

ids print as a large list of it's contents; *i.e.* So, this is good; but I need the duplicate.....

```
1234
8903
7465
6654
1234 # example dup value
....
```

**Goal: How could I iterate through all of this, then use a an if statement to do something if the duplicate is found?**

---

**Update**; I am trying this per answered suggestion: *(current code, recent attempt)*

```
def get_excel_data(self):
"""Places excel data into pandas dataframe"""

    excel_data = pandas.read_excel(self.find_file())
    columns = pandas.DataFrame(columns=excel_data.columns.tolist())
    excel_data = pandas.concat([excel_data, columns])

    for row in excel_data.itertuples():
        ids = excel_data["IDS"] # works, yes, list of values

        for i,id in enumerate(ids):
            print (i, id)
            if id in ids[:i]:
                print (id) # prints 0 nan, all i want is dup
```

and getting the below:

```
0 nan
```

Comment: Is `ids` a list?

Comment: What is `ids`? Is it a `pd.Series`?

Comment: You don't need split.  That was for changing a string of numbers into a list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use slicing to remove the current item and see if it still exists.

```
IDS='''1234 8903 7465 6654 1234'''

IDS = IDS.split()
print IDS

for i,id in enumerate(IDS):
    print i, id
    if id in IDS[:i]:
        print "duplicate", id
```

output:

```
[sri@localhost 00]$ python test.py
['1234', '8903', '7465', '6654', '1234']
0 1234
1 8903
2 7465
3 6654
4 1234
duplicate 1234
```

Comment: I'm getting this error on the prints in your code: 'Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(i, id)? (<unknown>, line 56)'

Comment: When I add the parentheses i then get this error: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'IDS' referenced before assignment"

Comment: Why are you using capital IDS

Comment: I have to declare my ids value, statically?

Comment: No, any list will work.  Static, dynamic; doesn't matter

Comment: IDS needs to be defined when you start the loop.

Comment: I used capital IDS because I thought that you had used IDS.

Comment: That was a previous attempt; I only have one 'id' variable - but tried adding another in caps per your suggestion. I've updated with full recent code attempt.

Comment: for i,id in enumerate(IDS): id is defined here